# Getting Webpack invalidation error when trying to start expo dev server

Tags: webpack, expo

I run `npm run start` and then press w to open web, but then I get this:

```
    Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Starting Webpack on port 19006 in development mode.
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'module'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'dgram'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'dns'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'http2'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'net'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'tls'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'child_process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
```

Anyone know what could be causing this and any potential solutions?

I've googled for hours and have found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be caused by mismatches of the webpack version. Make sure that your webpack version is exactly the same as @expo/webpack-config uses.

E.g. this combination of packages resolved the issue for me:

```
"@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
"webpack": "4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
```

Comment: For future readers, the "current" versions to use are in @expo/webpack-config's package.json
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/main/packages/webpack-config/package.json